# Passing var tuple to Enum value

Tags: ios, swift

Passing variable based tuple directly to enum with Tuple based values results in compilation error. For example:

I have an enum as below:

```
enum AnswerType  {
    case Objective(Int)
    case Subjective(question: Int, answer: String)
}

var stAnswer = (question: 1, answer: "Student's Answer")

let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(stAnswer) //Compilation error here - "Missing argument for parameter answer in call"
```

This gives compiler error with Swift 2.1. But when I change `stAnswer` to constant using let it works fine. Anyone having idea whats causing the compiler error here?

Comment: Curious little compiler idiosyncrasy. I've come across weird tuple behavior, too. Perhaps you should file a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com). In the short term, if you really need the `var stAnswer` rather than `let stAnswer`, then change `answerType` to `let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(question: stAnswer.question, answer: stAnswer.answer)`. (I know it's inelegant, but it seems less offensive than alternatives, to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift cannot handle passing a `var` this way. It can only pass a constant tuple to initialize associated data. This is most likely just an unimplemented feature in the compiler, and I recommend opening a radar (bugreport.apple.com).

The easiest solution is to just declare the tuple as a constant:

```
let stAnswer = (question: 1, answer: "Student's Answer")
let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(stAnswer)
```

If that isn't practical, then make a constant copy before you pass it (which is what the compiler should be able to do automatically).

```
var stAnswer = (question: 1, answer: "Student's Answer")
let values = stAnswer
let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(values)
```

You could also get fancy and use a closure to force a copy. This feels a bit over-tricky to me, but some may prefer it:

```
let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective({stAnswer}())
```

You can also use @Rob's solution from the comments (copied here for future readers), which is fine IMO:

```
let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(question: stAnswer.question, answer: stAnswer.answer)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `typealias` doesn't suffer from this curious behavior:

```
typealias SubjectiveType = (question: Int, answer: String)

enum AnswerType  {
    case Objective(Int)
    case Subjective(SubjectiveType)
}

var stAnswer = SubjectiveType(question: 1, answer: "Student's Answer")
stAnswer.answer = "Student's revised answer"

let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(stAnswer)
```

Or you can use `struct` for `SubjectiveType`, too, and accomplish something very similar.

Answer (score 1):

To use the tuple as the enum's value, double brace the tuple, thus:

```
enum AnswerType  {
    case Objective(Int)
    case Subjective((question: Int, answer: String)) 
    // One tuple value, rather than two non-tuple values
}

var stAnswer = (question: 1, answer: "Student's Answer")

let answerType = AnswerType.Subjective(stAnswer) // No error now...
```